# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken when login using two devise model (user and admin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I create an app using two devise model, user and admin.

I'm following the devise wiki from this link, I'm using the option 1
[How To: Add an Admin Role](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role)

So I open two page at the same time, the user login page and the admin login page.
When I login in the admin login page it succeed but when I login on the user page it raise an error ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken same goes with the other way.

But if I refresh the page first then I login it will succeed.

Are they using the same AuthenticityToken? So when the admin logged in, the AuthenticityToken is changed so when I try to login with the user it raise an InvalidAuthenticityToken?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are seeing is expected.This is because the value of csrf token changes once you sign in,expiring the old value.

Comment: thank you @arun, any solution or work around? because if I want to login in the same time as an user and an admin, it's a bit annoying.

Comment: Try different browsers or you could use multiple localhosts by changing port number using rails s -p [port number]

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround to disable CSRF protection for the `sign_in` action in the `ApplicationController`. Look here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3102